# Is the difference between two regular expressions a new regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

Let say the following:

Given `Ax` and `Bx` two literals which represent `POSIX` regular expressions.

Let def A as the set of literals that match `Ax`. The same def for B.

Using [relative complement operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), is there always regular expression for $A/B$ set, for every pair of `Ax,Bx`?

I attach an example:

```
Ax := a.*
Bx := a.*b$
// The difference A/B would be
Cx := a.*[^b]$
```

Comment: Have you checked the [closure properties of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties)?

Comment: No, I didn't. That comment answers directly this question. Can you post that information as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While regular languages are indeed closed under set difference, there is no nice way of effecting this operation on regular expressions. Indeed, even regular expression *complementation* can result in an exponential blow-up. One simple example is the regular expression $r_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j \neq i} \sigma_j)^*$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_N\}$, which corresponds to all words which do not have all letters of the alphabet. This regular expression has polynomial length (in $n$), but every regular expression for $\Sigma^* \setminus L(r_n)$ has exponential length.

Comment: What is $L(r_n)$? May you explain why is it exponential in size?

Comment: The language of $r_n$.

Answer (score 4):

Regular languages are [closed under relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties). Since regular expressions encode exactly the regular languages, you can always find a regular expression that matches the relative complement of two other regular expressions.